How can I parallelize nodes in LangGraph without having to wait for the slowest one to finish if it's not needed?
I'm trying to run multiple nodes in parallel to reduce latency but don't want to have to wait for all nodes to finish if I determine from early ones that finish that I don't need all of them.
Here's a simple graph example to illustrate the problem. It starts with 2 nodes in parallel: setting a random number and getting city preference from some source. If the random number is 1-50, "NYC" is assigned as city regardless of city preference, but if random number is 51-100, the city preference is used.
class State(TypedDict):
    random_number: int
    city: str
    city_preference: str

graph: StateGraph = StateGraph(state_schema=State)


def set_random_number(state):
    random_number = 1  # Hardcode to 1 for testing
    print(f"SET RANDOM NUMBER: {random_number}")
    return {"random_number": random_number}


def get_city_preference(state):
    time.sleep(4)  # Simulate a time-consuming operation
    city_preference = "Philadelphia"
    print(f"GOT CITY PREFERENCE: {city_preference}")
    return {"city_preference": city_preference}


def assign_city(state):
    city = "NYC" if state["random_number"] <= 50 else state["city_preference"]
    print(f"ASSIGNED CITY: {city}")
    return {"city": city}


graph.add_node("set_random_number", set_random_number)
graph.add_node("get_city_preference", get_city_preference)
graph.add_node("assign_city", assign_city)

graph.add_edge(START, "set_random_number")
graph.add_edge(START, "get_city_preference")
graph.add_edge("set_random_number", "assign_city")
graph.add_edge("get_city_preference", "assign_city")
graph.add_edge("assign_city", END)

graph_compiled = graph.compile(checkpointer=MemorySaver())

input = {"random_number": 0, "city": "Nowhere", "city_preference": "N/A"}
config = {
    "configurable": {"thread_id": "test"},
    "recursion_limit": 50,
}
state = graph_compiled.invoke(input=input, config=config)


The problem with the above and various conditional edge implementations I've tried, is that the graph always waits to assign city until the slow get_city_preference node completes even if the set_random_number node has already returned a number that doesn't require city preference (i.e., 1-50).
Is there a way to stop a node running in parallel from blocking execution of subsequent nodes if that node's output isn't needed later in the graph?
